# How to access source data from a data point of a pivot datatable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, datatables, pivot-table

In Excel you can double click on any value in a Pivot Table and it will give you the data extract from your original source data set. Is there a way or similar feature to receive the same extract from a data point of a pivot datatable in Shiny?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    dataTableOutput("pivot_table"),
    dataTableOutput("extract_table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    data <- iris
    
    pivot_data <- data %>% count(Species)
    
    extracted_data <- reactive(
      data %>% semi_join(pivot_data[input$pivot_table_rows_selected, ])
    )
    
    output$pivot_table <- renderDataTable(pivot_data)
    output$extract_table <- renderDataTable(extracted_data())
  }
)
```

[image]